# Using CSS Float property to position SVG Image

Tags: css, svg

I'm replacing a .png logo for a .svg logo and my CSS `float: left` parameter no longer works, the SVG just keeps dropping in the center. What do I need to change to make this image always float to the left side?
Thanks

```css
#NavRow{
height: 50px;
padding: 6px;
}
#Header_logo {
position: relative;
float: left;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavRow">
    <a href="link.to.homepage">
    <img id="Header_logo" src="http://kompozer.net/images/svg/Mozilla_Firefox.svg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to specify a size for the svg

Comment: ... because SVGs are based on vectors, and not pixels, which means they have no "natural" dimensions.